# How do I start a Camel route with autoStartup=false

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I want to control when my route starts up using a `RoutePolicy`. Therefore, I have defined it with `autoStartup=false`

```
<camel:route id="myRoute" routePolicyRef="myRoutePolicy" autoStartup="false">
    <!-- details omitted -->
</camel:route>
```

To start the route, I tried:

```
public class MyRoutePolicy implements RoutePolicy {
    
    // Does NOT work!
    @Override
    public void onInit(Route route) {
        if(shouldStartRoute(route)) {
            camelContext.startRoute(route.getId());
        }
    }

    // More stuff omitted
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. The Javadoc for `CamelContext.startRoute(String)` may explain why:

> Starts the given route if it has been previously stopped

How do I start a route that hasn't previously been stopped?

I'm using Camel 2.8.0 and upgrading is not an option.

I can start the route using a JMX console, but I don't want to depend on JMX.

Comment: Have you looked into [route policies](https://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html)? With Camel 2.8 you are getting limited support though. Maybe it still works for you.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, I'm calling `camelContext.startRoute("myRoute");` from a route policy in an attempt to start the route

Answer (score 4):

I've been debugging Camel. It seems that `CamelContext.startRoute(String)` does not start a route with autoStartup=false.

The right way to start a route is:

```
ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
```

But it didn't work for me in my `RoutePolicy`:

```
public class MyRoutePolicy implements RoutePolicy {

    // Does NOT work either!
    @Override
    public void onInit(Route route) {
        if(shouldStartRoute(route)) {
            ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
        }
    }

    // More stuff omitted
}
```

The problem here is that `route.getConsumer()` returns `null`. You have to wait until the Camel context is initialized to call `ServiceHelper.startService(consumer)`. So here is what does work:

```
public class MyRoutePolicy extends EventNotifierSupport implements RoutePolicy {
    private final Collection<Route> routes = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void onInit(Route route) {
        routes.add(route);
        CamelContext camelContext = route.getRouteContext().getCamelContext();
        ManagementStrategy managementStrategy = camelContext.getManagementStrategy();
        if (!managementStrategy.getEventNotifiers().contains(this)) {
            managementStrategy.addEventNotifier(this);
        }
    }

    // Works!
    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
        if(event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
            for(Route route : routes) {
                if(shouldStartRoute(route)) {
                    ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // More stuff omitted
}
```

Comment: is theare an issue on Camel Jira for that?

Comment: No, it's not really a bug

Answer (score 1):

When using Java DSL you can define your route as per example: `from("myEndpoint").autoStartup(isMyConfigEnabled())...`, where `isMyConfigEnabled()` is the method having the logic for your route to be started or not.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I was configuring `.noAutoStartup()`, then later calling `context.startRoute(myRouteId)`, but it wasn't starting.

I found the problem for me was that I needed to first call `context.start()`, since it initializes some state inside the CamelContext which will make the subsequent `startRoute` call actually work.

Answer (score 0):

While OP's answer started the route, it did not stop it, causing integrations tests to run very long. To also stop the routes, you need to extend `notify()` with something like

```
  if (event instanceof CamelContextStoppingEvent)
  {
     for (Route route : routes)
     {
        if (shouldStartRoute(route))
        {
           ServiceHelper.stopService(route.getConsumer());
        }
     }
  }
```